# Does Unity XR Plugin (Oculus) Use Centre of Visor or Head as Coordinate Origin for Tracking in VR?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinates, virtual-reality, oculus

Is the Unity XR plugin (Oculus) coordinate origin the centre of the visor or head?

I am developing an auditory test in VR using the Oculus quest 2 and Unity using the XR toolkit. I was wondering if anyone knew if tracking of the head is based on the centre of the visor, or the centre of the head?

Answer (score 0):

It is based on position of headset so it tracking the eye object.
Do you know that you can use Quest Link to test application without building, it should help you to make adjustment on the fly. Just remember that changes in Playmode aren't saved.